# Using back button doesn't clear old content

Tags: gwt, browser, back-button, gwt-platform, gwt-mvp

I'm using gwtp and I have some troubles with the browsers back button.
My DefaultPlace is a login page (root content). If the the login is correct, it directs you to a welcome page (MainPagePresenter) with a menu bar. This menu bar is always visible when going through its items. Clicking on an item reveals specific content (setInSlot) . When you use the back button it changes the token name to the token used before but you still see the old content.

My question is: How do I get back to the content which was shown before?

Comment: You said that you already solved the problem; could you consider adding how you did it as a self-answer, for the benefit of people who might come across this later asking the same thing? (Or if @Vale1501’s answer was right, just accept that so we know this is solved?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud use the GWTP presenter lifecycle. When you use back button, the previous presenter is revealed. You should override `onReveal()` and `onHide()` to clean or save the presenter and view state. 
If you want clean a presenter when the place changed, you should override `onHide()` and in the body you can clean the view before the place change.